# Extracting data from a PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I have a system that ultimately creates a PDF files from html file. It works very similar to a mail merge. It grabs data from a database, merge's the data into palceholders in the html document and then converts the html file to a pdf.

When I am unit testing the html file I can look at the values in my place holder. For example if I had a  John Smith  and I want to validate that the name is "John Smith" I simply look the value of the div after the merge.

I need to do something similar with validating the data in the pdf. Using pdfbox and itext I was able to extract text from a location as well as text from the document but I can't find anything that would let me create a "tag/placeholder/..." and extract information from it similar to what I do with the html file.

Is this possible with a pdf?

Comment: Based on your description I'm not sure this approach is possible, but instead of creating the actual PDF consider mocking the API which generates the PDF to be able to verify the API was called with the expected values.

Comment: I've already done something similar. What my management is looking for me to create something that they can take the end result (pdf) and do qa on every 1000 or so in production

Comment: You could compare the rendering… but the problem is that the rendering may be slightly different in different jdk versions. Another thing would be a tagged PDF, but this is poorly supported in PDFBox or very difficult to do, and text extraction doesn't have anything related to it. A third idea might be beads… these are like invisible rectangles that go around parts of text. Your text could get these beads and then use their coordinates for a region extraction (conversion to screen coordinates is needed). Not as difficult as tagging, but still not easy.

Answer (score 0):

That's perfectly possible using pdf2Data, which is a solution from the iText suite.

You can find the demo here
http://pdf2data.online/

It essentially does exactly what you described, you are given a viewer and some tools that allow you to define areas of interest (what you called 'placeholders').

Areas of interest can be defined using:

- coordinates
- relative to other areas of interest
- relative to text or regular expressions
- matching a certain regular exression
- matching a table
- etc

The tool then stores your template as an XML file, and you can use java or .NET code to extract information from a PDF that matches the template.

You are given either a json-like datastructure, or an XML file.
That should make it relatively straightforward to test whether a given area of interest contains a piece of text.